# python NameError: name 'pay_off' is not defined

Tags: python, undefined, nameerror

When I try the code this way it works good:

```
#this block of code will get the necessary inputs from the user

or_balance=balance=float(input('Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: '))
int_rate=float(input('Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: '))
mon_int_rate=int_rate/12

#this block of code will deal with the inputs to get the outputs

mon_pay_low_bound=balance/12
mon_pay_up_bound=(balance*(1+mon_int_rate)*12)/12

def total_balance(mon_pay):
    balance=or_balance
    global num
    num=0
    while num<12:
        num+=1
        balance=balance*(1+mon_int_rate)-mon_pay

    return balance

#this block of code will get the result desired by using the bisection method

a=mon_pay_low_bound
b=mon_pay_up_bound
tol=.0000000000005
n=1
while n<999:
    c=(a+b)/2
    if total_balance(c)==0 or (b-a)/2<tol:

        break
    else:
        n+=1
        if total_balance(c)<0:
            b=c
        else:
            a=c

#this block of code will give the final results
print('RESULT')
print('Monthly payment to pay off debt in 1 year:',round(c,2))
print('Number of months needed:',num)
print('Balance',round(total_balance(c),2))
```

However, when I make the next simple changes:

```
while n<999:
    c=(a+b)/2
    if total_balance(c)==0 or (b-a)/2<tol:
        pay_off=c
        break
    else:
        n+=1
        if total_balance(c)<0:
            b=c
        else:
            a=c

#this block of code will give the final results
print('RESULT')
print('Monthly payment to pay off debt in 1 year:',round(pay_off,2))
print('Number of months needed:',num)
print('Balance',round(total_balance(pay_off),2))
```

I got the following error:

> NameError: name 'pay_off' is not defined ,

Why is that so?

Another question, can I get the number value out of `total_balance()` without using the global thing?

Comment: define the variable outside the while loop

Comment: @matcheek The problem isn't the `while` loop it's that he has set the variable in an `if/else`. If the `if` never evaluates to true then the variable is never set which is the likely cause of the `NameError`

Answer (score 0):

If this `total_balance(c)==0 or (b-a)/2<tol` never evaluates to `True` then `pay_off` will never be set. So once `pay_off` is referenced in your final results block of print statements if it hasn't been set you will get a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's because the `total_balance(c)==0 or (b-a)/2<tol` conditional is never evaluating to True. I tried with the inputs 2000 (for current balance) and .13 (for interest rate), and it seemed to work correctly. Note that it took 52 iterations of the loop to achieve that result (I added a `print n` after the end of the loop to see).

I think your best option is to add a test to make sure that the answer was actually found - something like:

```
pay_off=0
while n<999:
    c=(a+b)/2
    if total_balance(c)==0 or (b-a)/2<tol:
        pay_off=c
        break
    else:
        n+=1
        if total_balance(c)<0:
            b=c
        else:
            a=c
if pay_off == 0:
    print "I couldn't determine the payoff amount in %d iterations" % n
```

This initializes `pay_off` whether or not it's actually reached, so you won't get a `NameError`, and you can then detect and warn the user that the algorithm didn't find a good answer.

Try playing around with the maximum value of `n` - I tried a `while n<50` to verify that I get a NameError if the conditional isn't reached. I suspect that with whatever inputs your using, the bisect method needs more than 999 iterations to find the answer. Increasing the size of `tol` should also allow you to achieve an answer with less iterations.